# Redefining an Excel range dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

Please excuse a question from someone who is most certainly out of his Excel depth, but I'm sure it will seem quite basic to many of you here.

I have defined several ranges of blocks of 10x10 data in my spreadsheet called (for example) Range1, Range2 etc. In my INDEX function call I currently hardcode the relevant table I'm interested in.

I would like to be able to dynamically specify the table to use based on user input, e.g in this simple example, use Range1 in my function if user input=1, Range2 if user input = 2 etc.

Or perhaps have my INDEX function use a generic range eg RangeX which is then 'mapped' to the relevant table.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Though a novice in many ways I'm happy to give anything a try, including VBA if necessary.

Thank you for you time

Comment: So, basically, you have a formula that is, say `=Index(A1:A10,match(B1,myNamedRange,0))` and you want to be able to type, say `myOtherNamedRange` in cell `D100` and have the formula switch out `myNamedRange` with `myOtherNamedRange`?  If so, you can use `INDIRECT()`: `=Index(A1:A10,match(B1,INDIRECT(D100),0))`

Comment: Thanks @BruceWayne for the quick response; I'll check out Indirect now.

Comment: Very many thanks, it looks like it might be the answer. I'd never never have found that in a million years! Thanks again